# How to hide a drop down menu after user clicks on an item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a dropdown menu using bootstrap with the following code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Examples    </a><ul class="dropdown-menu" id="examples">
      <li><a href="#" class="example" id="atlas" data-example-name="atlas">Atlas</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="example" id="map" data-example-name="map"> Map</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

However, I am having trouble hiding the dropdown menu after a user clicks on one of the menu items. I have tried using Jquery, giving the following code:

```
$("#atlas").click(function(){
    $("#examples").show();
})
```

but it requires me to click on a menu item twice (first time to perform its desired action, second time to finally hide it).

Comment: I suggest you to add a "toggled" class that will show the menu, you can also add CSS transitions on it.. (sorry I don't have time to build an example)
The jQuery will just have a ToggleClass method that will add or remove

Comment: are you trying to hide the entire drop down menu, or just the list items?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot that could be done to improve this but mainly you just need to call hide on the menu when an element is clicked. [Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/lupos/pen/RadQKY) of it working.

```
// show/hide the menu when examples is clicked
$(".dropdown-toggle").on("click", function () {
  $(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
});

// hide the menu when an exmple is clicked
$(".example").on("click", function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu").hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
$('.example').click(function(){ $('#examples').hide(); });
```

Comment: this blocks the drop-down menu from expanding even when clicked.

Comment: can you update my fiddle with the code that gives you problems ?
https://jsfiddle.net/arnLfmjk/1/

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it on fiddle, but here is the site I am working on http://brain-vr.com/surfaceviewer/  Look at the examples tab on the top left corner.

Comment: You have two items with ID examples in your view

Comment: // Load demo models.
    $("#examples li a").click(function(e) {
      current_request++;
      $(this).closest('ul').parent().removeClass('open');

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to this code.

dropdown-menu show always items. you click an item, hide it.

```
$('.example').on('click', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/qg3v5v0d/)

Answer (score -1):

You can bind your event to the li itself, and hide it when clicked:

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jjs0qxhx/).

If you want to use a class, you can do:

```
$('.example').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rL007axs/1/) using the class.

Comment: why the downvote on code that does what the OP requested?